# Getting the datatypes of Mysql into the Java program

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Is there any way to get the DataTypes of the MySQL database into a java program?

Comment: I thought of using the getKeyword() method. But it returns all the keywords in MySQL. what can i do to get only the datatype keywords??

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean here? The names of the datatypes? What purpose do you need this for?

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of all data types available regardless of the specific implementation in your DB or do you want to get schema meta data, i.e. a listing of all tables and their columns with data types?

Comment: @foampile I'm trying to get the list of all datatypes available in a database regardless of a specific implementation.

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie I'm working on building a MySQL Browser GUI. The main purpose  of building this system is to enable the user who has no knowledge of sql syntax, to create, modify and delete tables in a database without the need to enter the actual query

Answer (score 4):

Use `getColumnTypeName()` on `ResultSetMetaData`.

An example of this would be:

```
public class getColumnDataTypes  
{  
     public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
     {
          String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
          String connString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3300/DATABASE,USERNAME,PASSWORD";

          Class.forName(driver);
          Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);

          Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

          //Query
          ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELCET * FROM table");

          ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();

          //Get number of columns returned
          int numOfCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();

          //Print out type for each column
          for(int i=1; i<=numOfCols; ++i)
          {
               System.out.println("Column [" + i + "] data type: " + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i));
          }

          //Close DB connection
          statement.close();          
          connection.close();    
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi we can do this just by implementing few classes and packages that java already has like-

1.CHAR, VARCHAR, BLOB, TEXT, ENUM, and SET ->
 java.lang.String, java.io.InputStream, java.io.Reader, java.sql.Blob, java.sql.Clob
2.FLOAT, REAL, DOUBLE PRECISION, NUMERIC, DECIMAL, TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, INTEGER, BIGINT->
java.lang.String, java.lang.Short, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Long, java.lang.Double, java.math.BigDecimal
3.DATE, TIME, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP->
java.lang.String, java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp

*MySQL Connector/J is flexible in the way it handles conversions between MySQL data types and Java data types.*

In general, any MySQL data type can be converted to a java.lang.String, and any numeric type can be converted to any of the Java numeric types, although round-off, overflow, or loss of precision may occur.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to get a list of your columns with data types then use system tables:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, 
COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = {YOUR_DB}
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DatabaseMetaData.getTypeInfo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTypeInfo%28%29) to retrieve a list of typenames in the database, the corresponding JDBC type and information like maximum precision, etc.